# Why doesn't my code work despite the placement of my external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the basis of how my document is written out. I have an external JavaScript file positioned at the top of the head element. Below it, I have code the references content from it. I would expect since the code is below the file it would work but it doesn't. It only works if I wrap the code in a `window.onload()` function. Or if I put the code in a script in the body element.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myJavaScript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(w); // w is a variable inside myJavaScript.js but throws an error stating "w is not defined".
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Why does this code behave this way? I have the file written on top of the code that calls content within it yet it still doesn't work.

EDIT: I found the error and it was that I wasn't defining the code in myJavaScript.js in the global scope. That's why the variable w never got through.

Comment: That should work fine. I just tested it (with "myJavaScript.js" containing just `w = 10;`) and it behaved as expected. Your other file must not be defining the variable globally; could you show us some of the code from it?

Comment: You were right, I wasn't defining it in the global scope. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to show us the relevant code in `myJavaScript.js` for us to know what's really going on, but it's fairly clear that either `w` isn't defined at the global scope in `myJavasScript.js` or `myJavaScript.js` isn't being loaded successfully.

Most likely `w` is not actually a globally scoped variable like you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your problems. You haven't probably define your "w" variable or you defined it away from global scope

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/686fb

try to add at the top of head:

```
var w = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Dollars to doughnuts, the `w` is being set in an `onload`.